# Java - FontMetrics without Graphics

Tags: java, awt, font-size, fontmetrics

How to get FontMetrics without use Graphics ? I want to get FontMetrics in constructor, now I do this way:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(5, 5, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
FontMetrics fm = bi.getGraphics().getFontMetrics(font);
int width = fm.stringWidth(pattern);
int height = fm.getHeight();
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this without graphics?

Comment: I create my own control, and I want to set preffred size in constructor

Comment: This is useful for getting font metrics when in a headless mode, i.e. a command line tool that processes fonts to bitmaps.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hmm... It is quite logical that you need graphics to get FontMetrics. Font height, width etc. can differ on various displays.

If you have some Component, you can use it for getting FontMetrics:

```
component.getFontMetrics(font);
```

Comment: @amorfis
Are you sure that font width and height depend on display while I have specified the font-size?

Answer (score 42):

No you do not necessarily need to get/use the graphics object:

```
Font font = new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,12);
Canvas c = new Canvas();
FontMetrics fm = c.getFontMetrics(font);
```

If you would now call `c.getGraphics()` it would return null. The canvas solution on the other hand will also work in [headless mode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html).

Comment: If I may expand ever so slightly on this - if you're reading a font from a file, remember to "derive" a font with a viable size (failing to remember to do so will result in values such as getMaxAscent/Descent returning 1):

`Font sourceFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontStream);`
`Font awtFont = sourceFont.deriveFont(72.0f);`
`Canvas canvas = new Canvas();`
`FontMetrics metrics = canvas.getFontMetrics(awtFont);`