# Error trying to Install Install4J made installer on Raspberry-Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, install4j, java

I made an installer with latest Install4J and want to install the package on a raspberry pi for testing.

It's running latest Raspbian Image with latest updates and openJDK v.1.8.0.40

If I try to start the installer in unattended mode (-q) I get a "Starting Installer..." message and then I get a NullPointerException.

This is the console output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./plentyBase.sh -q
Starting Installer ...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.currentManager(RepaintManager.java:262)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4799)
    at java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3303)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setFont(JComponent.java:2756)
    at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(LookAndFeel.java:208)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installDefaults(BasicPanelUI.java:66)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(BasicPanelUI.java:56)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:664)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(JPanel.java:153)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:126)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:86)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:109)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:117)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.FormPanel.<init>(FormPanel.java:50)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.init(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:67)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.UnattendedScreenExecutor.<init>(UnattendedScreenExecutor.java:48)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.InstallerUnattendedScreenExecutor.<init>(InstallerUnattendedScreenExecutor.java:10)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Installer.java:88)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:58)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:57)
An error occurred:
java.lang.NullPointerException
Error log: /tmp/install4jError7183942791429390239.log
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.currentManager(RepaintManager.java:262)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4799)
    at java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3303)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setFont(JComponent.java:2756)
    at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(LookAndFeel.java:208)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installDefaults(BasicPanelUI.java:66)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(BasicPanelUI.java:56)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:664)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(JPanel.java:153)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:126)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:86)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:109)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:117)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.FormPanel.<init>(FormPanel.java:50)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.init(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:67)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.UnattendedScreenExecutor.<init>(UnattendedScreenExecutor.java:48)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.InstallerUnattendedScreenExecutor.<init>(InstallerUnattendedScreenExecutor.java:10)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Installer.java:88)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:58)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:57)
```

This is the content of the error log:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /tmp/install4jError7183942791429390239.log 
Exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.currentManager(RepaintManager.java:262)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4799)
    at java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3303)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setFont(JComponent.java:2756)
    at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(LookAndFeel.java:208)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installDefaults(BasicPanelUI.java:66)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(BasicPanelUI.java:56)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:664)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(JPanel.java:153)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:126)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:86)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:109)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:117)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.FormPanel.<init>(FormPanel.java:50)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.init(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:67)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.UnattendedScreenExecutor.<init>(UnattendedScreenExecutor.java:48)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.InstallerUnattendedScreenExecutor.<init>(InstallerUnattendedScreenExecutor.java:10)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Installer.java:88)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:58)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:57)

System properties:

java.runtime.name=OpenJDK Runtime Environment
exe4j.moduleName=/home/pi/plentyBase.sh
sun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/arm
java.vm.version=25.40-b08
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
path.separator=:
java.vm.name=OpenJDK Zero VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
sun.os.patch.level=unknown
install4j.exeDir=/home/pi/
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir=/home/pi/plentyBase.sh.939.dir
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_40-internal-b04
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
i4jv=0
java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/endorsed
os.arch=arm
java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
line.separator=

java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
os.name=Linux
exe4j.totalDataLength=36451286
sun.java2d.noddraw=true
sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
java.library.path=/home/pi/plentyBase.sh.939.dir/user::/usr/java/packages/lib/arm:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/jni:/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version=52.0
os.version=4.4.50+
i4j.vpt=true
install4j.cwd=/home/pi
user.home=/home/pi
user.timezone=Etc/UTC
java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob
file.encoding=UTF-8
install4j.jvmDir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre
java.specification.version=1.8
java.class.path=i4jruntime.jar
user.name=pi
java.vm.specification.version=1.8
sun.java.command=com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher launch 0   com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer -q
java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre
sun.arch.data.model=32
user.language=en
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
java.vm.info=interpreted mode
java.version=1.8.0_40-internal
java.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
sun.boot.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/classes
java.awt.headless=true
install4j.appDir=/home/pi/
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
file.separator=/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
sun.font.fontmanager=sun.awt.X11FontManager
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.cpu.isalist=
```

The same installer is working fine on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in a virtual machine.

Edit:
I think it comes from JPanel init to get FontMetrics?

Found it here: [NPE when calling new JPanel() in headless (RepaintManager.currentManager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020442/npe-when-calling-new-jpanel-in-headless-repaintmanager-currentmanager)

So it looks like a bug in install4J.

If I open the installer on desktop/gui mode on raspberry pi the installer is working fine.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: It's not related to install4j, it's the AWT that does not work,

Comment: Yea I know that it is AWT related, but as far as I understand you can use
Canvas c = new Canvas();
FontMetrics fm = c.getFontMetrics(font);
(found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18123024/3486801) to avoid this Exception.

Comment: No, that's something different. This is not something we can workaround.

Comment: So there is nothing we can do here to get it to work for headless devices?

Comment: Generally, headless mode works, but only it the AWT handles it properly.